# How can I use parameter in a SQL script file

Tags: sql, parameters

I want to create a database with a SQL script file but I cannot give a parameter instead of database name how can I solve this?

```
Declare @Test as nvarchar(max)

CREATE DATABASE [@Test] ON  PRIMARY 
  ( NAME = N'@Test', 
    FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\@Test.mdf', 
    SIZE = 11264KB , MAXSIZE = 51200KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 LOG ON 
 ( NAME = N'@Test_log', 
   FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\@Test_1.ldf' , 
   SIZE = 9216KB , MAXSIZE = 25600KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
GO

ALTER DATABASE [@Test] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
```

Comment: How are you planning to use this parameter? You are declaring it, but you're not giving it a value.

Comment: I run this in c# and ı want to send a valu in there

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass in parameters to a SQL Server script called with sqlcmd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814302/how-to-pass-in-parameters-to-a-sql-server-script-called-with-sqlcmd)

Comment: And how are you running this in C#? Can you include a sample of your code in your question?

Answer (score 3):

If you use [SQLCMD compatibility mode in SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx), you can use SQLCMD parameters:

```
:setvar dbname YourDatabase

CREATE DATABASE $(dbname) ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = $(dbname), 
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\$(dbname).mdf', 
  SIZE = 11264KB , MAXSIZE = 51200KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
LOG ON 
 ( NAME = N'$(dbname)_log', 
   FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\$(dbname)_log.ldf' , 
   SIZE = 9216KB , MAXSIZE = 25600KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
GO

ALTER DATABASE $(dbname) SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
```

Those parameters can also be specified using the `SQLCMD` command line tool on the command line

You can enable the "SQLCMD mode" in SQL Server Management Studio under `Tools > Options`

[image]

And that change **only** affects new windows in SSMS being opened - it does not apply to already open windows.