# How to pass param from bat script to sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, parameter-passing, sql-scripts

test.bat

```
SQLCMD -s SQL-SL_SQL01 -E -I “C:\Users\sqladmin\test.sql” -v p = "%1"
```

test.sql

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' , N'SoftwareMicrosoftMSSQLServerMSSQLServer' , N'DefaultData' , REG_SZ , N’${p}’ GO
```

In cmd prompt, passing this : `test.bat f:\sql`

but getting a error like this,

> sqlcmd: ':sql', invalid argument

Comment: Scripting variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass in parameters to a SQL Server script called with sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814302/how-to-pass-in-parameters-to-a-sql-server-script-called-with-sqlcmd)

Comment: Do not use “smart quotes”. Use the regular style quotes like you have on the "argument".